# ¿Cómo evito que se vaya a un bucle infinito al tratar de separar una lista en 2?, con criterios de selección

Tags: lista, prolog, swi-prolog

Intento separar 2 listas desde una primera dependiendo de una variable pivote.
Pero por alguna razón entra en un bucle infinito del que no sale.

```
dividir(A,[],Lmen,Lmay). %caso de parada lista original vacia

dividir(A,[L|R],Lmen,Lmay):- %comprobaciones mayor menor separadas por un OR
    (L =< A,(append(Lmay,L,Lmay2),dividir(A,R,Lmen,Lmay2)));
    (L > A,(append(Lmen,L,Lmen2),dividir(A,R,Lmen2,Lmay))).
```

Por alguna razón no soy capaz de ver donde falla.
Una ayuda se agradeceria.

Answer (score 0):

Tu procedimiento entra en un bucle infinito porque en el primer paso de la recursión la llamada a `append/3` tiene infinitas alternativas (tanto el primer parametro como el tercero están sin instanciar). El segundo parametro al append debería ser una lista pero es un elemento (`L`).
Al continuar con la recursión vuelve a intentar hacer el append ahora con el primer y segundo parametros instanciados pero como el segundo no es una lista falla.

Aquí una posible solución sin utilizar `append/3`:

```
dividir(A, L, Menor, Mayor):-
 dividir1(L, A, Menor, Mayor).  % Cambio el orden de los parametros para que SWI lo optimice

dividir1([], _, [], []).
dividir1([B|R], A, Menor1, Mayor1):-
  (  B > A
  -> Menor1-Mayor1=Menor-[B|Mayor]
  ;  Menor1-Mayor1=[B|Menor]-Mayor
  ),
  dividir1(R, A, Menor, Mayor).
```

Caso de prueba:

```
?- dividir(5, [2,4,6,8,3,5,7], Menor, Mayor).
Menor = [2, 4, 3, 5],
Mayor = [6, 8, 7].
```